# Access Versions of Package Dependencies on the Frontend

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I'm writing the (React) frontend for a library package and would like to make it explicit to the end user which version of the library I'm using, on the frontend. Other than doing it manually or through Node.js, I have no idea how to do this.

I wonder if there is a way of turning the `package.json` for the frontend into a global, JSON variable for the frontend to access, without Node.js hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With a bundler

If you're using a bundler like webpack or rollup (which you should be if this is an npm package), you can simply do...

**commonjs**

```js
window.package = require('./package.json');
```

**esm**

```js
import pkg from './package.json' assert {type: 'json'};

window.package = pkg;
```

The bundler will resolve the import and bundle the json into your output script making it available when run in a browser at `window.package.version`.

If you're using Vite as a bundler, or rollup, in order to make import assertions work, use the `@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions` plugin. One example with React:

```js
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      babel: {
        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"],
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

## Without a bundler

If you aren't using a bundler, you can still do this using [modules](https://caniuse.com/?search=modules)

**index.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Import package.json</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import pkg from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };
      alert(pkg.version);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "js",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

**Caveat:** If you just open `index.html` on your local machine, you'll get a CORS error. You need to actually serve this file. A quick way to serve this website on Mac is using python..

```bash
python3 -m http.server 9000
```

Then open `localhost:9000` in your browser and you'll see your package version

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the message so far. I'm using Vite + React + TS right now. And, with the `require` method, I get the classic `require is not defined`. And, with the other method I get `experimental syntax 'importAssertions' isn't currently enabled: Add @babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions` (working on adding this plugin right now).

Comment: I think [this Github comment fixes my use case](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4934#issuecomment-1131998445).

Comment: Vite actually uses es modules (no bundling) in development and then bundles with rollup in production. If you can get json imports working, the esm version under "with a bundler" should work for both